# How to push to Git branch from Jenkins job?

Tags: python, git, jenkins, branch, push

I have Jenkins job that calls Python script in it's configuration. Script creates few files and executes `git add path/to/new/files`, `git commit -m "foobar"` and then `git push -u origin my_branch`. If I call that script locally, needed files gets added and pushed to that branch. When Jenkins job calls that script, `git push` returns an error.

```
error: src refspec my_branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@example.com:my_project.git'
```

Any idea why's that? I need to be able to `git pull` created files afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telling Git the specific URL helped.

`git push -u git@example.com:my_project.git HEAD:my_branch`